# is a mixed-model suittable for my design?

Tags: mixed-model

I have data from an experiment I did a few months ago.
In short, I'm looking at postural sway using simple measures (i.e. 1 value per measure per condition).

The design was a 2x3 repeated measure. (2 feet position x 3 cognitive tasks). Each condition was performed 5 times for 30 trials per participant.

They were not told that the cognitive task changed between trials in the experiment. Our main goal was to see if changing the task without telling participant would affect their sway.

After the experiment, we realized that 9/25 participants figured it out. So of course, now we need to take that into account.

I did a simple 2x2x3 mixt ANOVA using the averaged of the 5 trials/participants for every condition and found that postural sway was only affected by the cognitive task for those who figured it out. However, I wonder if a linear mixed model would be more appropriate for my design considering that I have a between-subject variable (figuring it out) with different sizes ( 9 vs 16). Additionally, I expect that figuring it out would affect postural sway differently for every participant. Some might be "unsure", others might figure it out in the middle or as early as the first trial. Would the model be able to account for that somehow?

I'm new to the linear mixed-model. I heard it for the first time the other day so there is a lot that I don't understand about it. Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated !